# iPhone UIScrollView problem

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have `UIScrollView` in my view. Problem is that if I slightly scroll it than also it scrolls automatically to down, I mean scrolling does not stop at particular stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it's not quite clear what you mean by 'particular stage'. However, it sounds as though you might want to enable paging on the scrollview. This will enable you to make the scroll view 'sticky' at the page interval, so the view will stop scrolling at each page boundary rather than scroll in one continuous movement.